# spring data redis : default behavior of ZSetOperations

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I am trying to use `ZSetOperations` for updating/querying differents sorted sets in redis, but I noticed this behavior:
I am obtaining an instance  of `ZSetOperations` through `RedisTemplate` like this:

```
ZSetOperations zsetOps = redisTemplate.opsForZSet();
```

Which returns a singleton of `ZSetOperations`.
When adding new data to two sorted sets `A` and `B` everything is working fine.

When I query `A` through `zsetOps` it returns the expected results but when I am reusing the `zsetOps` attribute for querying `B` it returns nothing. It seems that the order of the update has an importance (`A` was updated first) and binds the `zsetOps` to only one sorted set, `A` in this case.

In conclusion `redisTemplate.opsForZSet()` is like `redisTemplate.boundZSetOps(keyName)` except it bounds it self implicitely to the first sorted sets it updates.

Is this the normal behavior ?

**Update**
Here is an example of the code highlighting the problem:

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

private ZSetOperations zsetOps;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    zsetOps = redisTemplate.opsForZSet();

}

public void save(Object post) {
   this.redisTemplate.executePipelined((RedisCallback<Object>) connection -> {
        zsetOps.add("A", post.getId(), post.getScoreA());
        zsetOps.add("B", post.getId(), post.getScoreB());
    });
}

// returns a Set of result
public Object findScoreA() {
      zsetOps.rangeWithScores("A", start, end);
}
// returns an empty set
public Object findScoreA() {
      zsetOps.rangeWithScores("B", start, end);
}
```

Comment: `DefaultZSetOperations` is just a wrapper to execute commands. Could you provide a simple and reproducible test case?

Comment: @mp911de I edited the question

Comment: `executePipelined` does not execute `zsetOps.add(…)` inside the pipeline as you're working with `ZSetOperations` and not the connection object inside the closure. Except for the pipelining issue, your code is fine.

Comment: @mp911de zsetOps.add(…) works fine inside the pipeline it adds the data the sorted sets without any problem .

Comment: Should have emphasized **inside the pipeline**. Commands are executed but without pipelining. You'll notice that when debugging the code.

Comment: I'll try without a pipeline

Comment: @mp911de thanks it worked without the pipeline. you can answer the question